# Add event handler to an element that not yet exists using on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an event handle to an element that will be created later in DOM.

Basically, what I am trying to do is that, when I click `p#one`, new element `p#two` will be created, then I click `p#two`, tell me "p#two" clicked. However, it doesn't work, I didn't get the `console.log` result of 'p#two clicked' after I click `p#two`.

I use `on()` to add click event to `p#two`. What do I do wrong?

Thanks.

Below is my example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>on() test</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="http://localhost/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('p#two').on('click', function() {
            console.log('p#two clicked');
        });


        $('p#one').click(function() {
            console.log('p#one clicked');
            $('<p id="two">two</p>').insertAfter('p#one');
        });

    }); // end doc ready
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="one">one</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click','p#two', function() {
    console.log('p#two clicked');
});
```

you can also use

```
$(document).on('click', 'p#two', function() {

});
```

Read more about **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**

you can also use **[`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)**

```
$('body').delegate('#two', 'click', function() {

});
```

Answer (score 13):

You can bind the $.on to a parent element that will always exist in dom like this.

```
$(document).on('click','p#two', function() {
            console.log('p#two clicked');
        });
```

**Note that:** you can replace `document` with any parent of the element that will always exist in dom, and the closer the parent the better.

Check doc of [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Live is depreciated. use $.on instead. Equivalent syntax of $.on for $.live and $.delegate

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

I would suggest you to use `$.on` for all event handling purposes as all other methods routes through $.on method under the hood.

Check the definition of these functions from jQuery source v.1.7.2

```
bind: function( types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
},
unbind: function( types, fn ) {
    return this.off( types, null, fn );
},

live: function( types, data, fn ) {
    jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
    return this;
},
die: function( types, fn ) {
    jQuery( this.context ).off( types, this.selector || "**", fn );
    return this;
},

delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, selector, data, fn );
},
undelegate: function( selector, types, fn ) {
    // ( namespace ) or ( selector, types [, fn] )
    return arguments.length == 1? this.off( selector, "**" ) : this.off( types, selector, fn );
}
```

You can see all methods are using `$.on` and `$.off` themselves. So using `$.on` you can at least save a function call though which isn't that significant most of the cases.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use Jquery.on

```
$('body').on('click','p#two', function() {
        console.log('p#two clicked');
    });
```

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated and replaced with `on()` in jQuery 1.7

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated in favor of `.on()` in jQuery 1.7